# ¿Es "chamo" usado en otros países aparte de Venezuela?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, venezuela

Yo crecí en Venezuela y siempre usaba la palabra `Chamo`. Pero no he escuchado en ningún otro país en donde usan la palabra.  Me pregunto si se usa en otros países.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que básicamente se usa en ciertas partes colindantes de Venezuela y en Venezuela misma. Fuera de ahí, lo dudo, acá en México se usa haciendo mofa de las telenovelas de Venezuela que llegaron a transmitirse acá. Fuera de eso, tampoco he visto que se use.

Answer (score 4):

El [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/) siempre es una buena ayuda para estas dudas. En este caso, indica:

> [**chamo, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=L1QJUJi36x0A13dt82x). (Del ingl. chum).
>   I.  1.  m. y f. ES, Cu, Ve. Niño o adolescente.
>   2.  Ve. juv. Amigo o compañero.
>   3.  ES. Persona, individuo.

Es decir, que se usa en El Salvador, Cuba y Venezuela para designar a un niño o adolescente, mientras que la acepción de amigo o compañero solamente se usa en Venezuela. Finalmente, solo en El Salvador se usa para definir a una persona en general.

Answer (score 2):

En Ecuador también se usa esa palabra, y es para referirse a los adolescentes, novio/a (chamo/a) y para el inexperto:

> Estás chamo todavía. *(Te falta aprender.)*

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chamo) dice que solo se usa en Venezuela con el significado de

> Ser humano de corta edad, en especial el que no ha llegado a la pubertad

Sin embargo [Asihablamos](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Chamo.php) dice que se usa en Colombia para referirse de forma peyorativa a los venezolanos. El propio traductor de Google sugiere que se usa también en Ecuador, con el significado que se le da en Venezuela (niño o persona inmadura).

[image]